# Terraform : Error decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field KeyValuePair.Environment.Value of type string

Tags: json, terraform

I copied this resource block from terraform code.When I trigger the pipeline I'm getting error and couldn't solve it.

```
locals {
        fedramp_source_types = ["activeDirectory", "azureActiveDirectory"]
        allowed_source_types = ["activeDirectory", "azureActiveDirectory", "googleDirectory"]
          }

module "service_definition" {
...
 env = [
 {
      name = "ALLOWED_SOURCE_TYPES",
      value = "${split(",", module.env_helper.is_legacy ? join(",", local.allowed_source_types) : join(",", local.fedramp_source_types))}"
    }]
}
```

Comment: There is no way we can know where the error is happening unfortunately.

Comment: Please add more information, or we cannot help you. What did you do, exactly, what's the result, what did you expect?

Comment: `split` returns a `list` type and the error claims it should be a `string`. That is the root cause, but we do not what you intended to do here, so unfortunately we cannot guess the fix.